# Analytical Badge - retired?

Tags: discussion, badges

I was just going through the stack exchange site and found this. The Analytical Badge means Visited every section of the FAQ (retired).

What does "retired" here mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means it is no longer awarded, as the way the help section is organised has changed completely compared to when the badge was originally awarded.